# Form with multi action

Tags: jquery, forms, action

I'm trying to create a form with multi action
if user select "option 1" action must be xxxxx.php and if user select "option 2" the action chang to another page

```
<form method="post" action="irancell-charge.php">
     <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="093x-xxxxxxx" maxlength="11">
            <!-- Select Basic -->
                 <div class="control-group">
                     <div class="controls">
                         <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-xlarge">
                                <option>option 1</option>
                                <option>optoin 2</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">send</button>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Give an id to your form (eg: "myform")
2. Give a value attribute to your options (eg: "option1", "option2")

Then

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="irancell-charge.php">
     <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="093x-xxxxxxx" maxlength="11">
            <!-- Select Basic -->
                 <div class="control-group">
                     <div class="controls">
                         <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-xlarge">
                                <option value="option1">option 1</option>
                                <option value="option2">optoin 2</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">send</button>
                    </form>


<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('selectbasic').onchange = function(){
    console.log('hola');
    if (this.value=='option1') {
        newAction='option1.php';
    } else if (this.value=='option2') {
        newAction='option2.php';
    } else {
        newAction='else.php';
    }
    document.getElementById('myform').action = newAction;
}
</script>
```

If you're using jQuery, you can replace the document.getElementById by $() or jQuery().

Answer (score -1):

you can use  onclick event in  tag and call javascript for submitting the form with different action

```
    onclick="submitform1()"

    <script type="text/javascript">

      submitform1(){

      document.myform.action = "xxxxx.php";
      document.submit();

    }

//for option2 submitform2
 submitform2(){

      document.myform.action = "yyyyy.php";
      document.submit();

    }

</script>
```

or second way

onselected event of select tag, you can call javascript and pass the option value ,based on option value you can determine the desired action

Comment: sorry but where can i put onclick? in a button or in a select tag?

Comment: This doesn't work, as the form needs to be submitted with the submit button, not with the select.